# Saving and loading a ggplot object defined using unsaved variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-loading

I want to save a ggplot object defined using a variable `var1`, which is not saved.

```r
library(ggplot2)
var1 <- 100
datfram <- data.frame(y=rnorm(var1))
ggp1 <- ggplot(datfram) + geom_point(aes(x=1:var1, y=y))
save(ggp1, file='temp.rdata')

load(file='temp.rdata')
ggp1
```

If I load the saved data file, R can't plot the object `ggp1` because `var1` is unknown. The error message is shown below.

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
 ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
 ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
 Caused by error:
 ! object 'var1' not found
```

I suspect that this is due to R's lazy loading mechanism. I could save `var1` in the data file as well, but I wonder if there is a way I can conveniently save a ggplot object without worrying about dependencies.

Comment: You should not attempt to store data in the `aes()`. Make sure the data is coming from the data.frame. If you did `aes(x=seq_along(y), y=y)` that would be fine since both values from from `y` in the data.frame.

Comment: Just for completeness: this is *not* due to lazy loading, and lazy loading does not happen here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MrFlick that you should refrain from using extern variables, but if you absolutely must, you should make sure that they are evaluated when passed to `ggplot` using the injection operator `!!`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".rdata")
tf2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".rdata")
var1 <- 100

datfram <- data.frame(y = rnorm(var1))
gg_wrong <- ggplot(datfram) + geom_point(aes(x = 1:var1, y = y))

## note the usage of !!
gg_good <- ggplot(datfram) + geom_point(aes(x = 1:!!var1, y = y))

save(gg_wrong, file = tf1)
save(gg_good, file = tf2)

rm(var1, gg_wrong, gg_good)
load(file = tf1)
load(file = tf2)

gg_wrong ## error
gg_good ## works
```